# Programmatically make the iPhone vibrate

Tags: iphone, iphone-vibrate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

How can you programmatically make the iPhone vibrate?

Any ideas, or tutorial links appreciated.

Comment: lots of good stuff already on stackOverflow too:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+vibrate

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Note that you need to add the AudioToolbox framework and import the following header file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Comment: do you need to put anything else? i tried this, and got several build errors. 

and can you do this multiple times?

Comment: @Sam: You need to `#import` the appropriate headers and link to the relevant frameworks.

Comment: Right-Click the Method and selecting "Find in documentation"

Comment: ah. got it. [15 characters.. wtf!]

Comment: Pretty dumb.... (the 15 char. minimum)

Comment: hey guys is it possible to  vibrate when the iphone is not on vibration(silent).

Comment: This isn't working for me. Do I have to add a framework?

Comment: @Jon Add the AudioToolbox framework

Comment: Thanks, ill do that, is it easy to add a sound as well along with the vibrate?

Comment: This only works if "Settings > Sounds > Vibrate on Ring" is ON (if silencer is switched off) and "Settings > Sounds > Vibrate on Silent" is ON (if silencer is switched on). Here is a (not perfect) workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22843899/1884907

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the *add(ing) the AudioToolbox framework* portion of this answer:

1. click the project from Project Navigator
2. click the target from the left-hand navigator
3. click *Build Phases* section at the top
4. expand the *Link Binary With Libraries* section
5. click little **+** (plus) sign
6. type `AudioToolbox.framework`
7. click *Add*