# How to vibtrate iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone

In my app, I have to ring an alarm in iPhone with vibrations at a particular time. How can I add the functionality of Vibration in my App. sample code will be better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [programmatically make iphone vibrate. ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080442/programmatically-make-iphone-vibrate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the iPhone vibrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

(Declared in AudioServices.h)