# Making the iPhone vibrate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, vibration

How can the iPhone be set to vibrate once?

For example, when a player loses a life or the game is over, the iPhone should vibrate.

Comment: Shake gesture is completely different than vibration. One is human-initiated, one device-initiated.

Answer (score 407, accepted):

From "[iPhone Tutorial: Better way to check capabilities of iOS devices](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/)":

There are two seemingly similar functions that take a parameter `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate`:

```
1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

> Both of the functions vibrate the iPhone. But, when you use the first
>   function on devices that don’t support vibration, it plays a beep
>   sound. The second function, on the other hand, does nothing on
>   unsupported devices. So if you are going to vibrate the device
>   continuously, as an alert, common sense says, use function 2.

First, add the AudioToolbox framework `AudioToolbox.framework` to your target in Build Phases.

Then, import this header file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Comment: Is this the only way to vibrate the phone? Why did they run it through AudioServices?

Comment: #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> is not required.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the vibration time to less than 1 sec?

Comment: I would like to add, that if vibration is off in Settings of iOS, user will not get vibration even if you use these commands.

Comment: Any info on general stance from Apple on vibration? Any case where they turned an app down because of improper vibration use?

Comment: In Swift: `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(UInt32(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))` (at least as of beta 2)

Comment: AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); Vibarate on iPhone proerly but it doesn't make any beep sound on iPad.

Comment: this works great when your app is in foreground state but what when in background state like,  bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
function 1 or function 2 for vibration
}];  this is not working. can you explain?

Comment: This functions are going to be deprecated in a future release of iOS.

Comment: Keep in mind that the device does not vibrate if your app’s audio session is configured with the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord audio session category. This ensures that vibration doesn’t interfere with audio recording.

Comment: how to increase/Decrease Vibration time.

Comment: Hello @FedeHenze How can we achieve vibration with the recording? Is there another way to achieve vibration wile recording?

Answer (score 46):

### Swift 2.0+

AudioToolbox now presents the `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` as a `SystemSoundID` type, so the code is:

```
import AudioToolbox.AudioServices

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

Instead of having to go thru the extra cast step

(Props to @Dov)

### Original Answer (Swift 1.x)

And, here's how you do it on **Swift** (in case you ran into the same trouble as I did)

Link against `AudioToolbox.framework` (Go to your project, select your target, build phases, Link Binary with Libraries, add the library there)

Once that is completed:

```
import AudioToolbox.AudioServices

// Use either of these
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

The cheesy thing is that `SystemSoundID` is basically a `typealias` (fancy swift `typedef`) for a `UInt32`, and the `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` is a regular `Int`. The compiler gives you an error for trying to cast from `Int` to `UInt32`, but the error reads as "Cannot convert to SystemSoundID", which is confusing. Why didn't apple just make it a Swift enum is beyond me.

@aponomarenko's goes into the details, my answer is just for the Swifters out there.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Swift 2/iOS 9/Xcode 7. I used `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` and it compiled fine

Answer (score 35):

A simple way to do so is with Audio Services:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> 
...    
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Comment: #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> and you'll need to add the AudioToolbox.framework to your project's Build Phases.

Answer (score 34):

I had great trouble with this for devices that had vibration turned off in some manner, but we needed it to work regardless, because it is critical to our application functioning, and since it is just an integer to a documented method call, it will pass validation. So I have tried some sounds that were outside of the well documented ones here: [TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary)

I have then stumbled upon 1352, which is working regardless of the silent switch or the settings on the device `(Settings->vibrate on ring, vibrate on silent)`.

```
- (void)vibratePhone;
{
     if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
     {
         AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1352); //works ALWAYS as of this post
     }
     else
     {
          // Not an iPhone, so doesn't have vibrate
          // play the less annoying tick noise or one of your own
          AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (1105);
     }
}
```

Comment: It's always better to use named aliases instead of magic constants, like kSystemSoundID_Vibrate instead 1352. I encourage you to update your answer.

Comment: Looks like he's not going to update it - why not edit the answer yourself?

Comment: I would agree using this magic 1352 is not ideal, but I can't find any other way to force a vibration even when the vibrate switch is off on the device. This seems to be the only way.

Comment: @JoelTeply I confirm, `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` not worked for me, but `1352` did. Where did you find this constant?

Comment: I wrote a for loop with integers starting past the published constants and figured out which one caused a vibrate

Comment: I can confirm that the iPhone vibrates even if the silent mode is activated on the iPhone. Great answer!

Comment: What I mean to say is that I hacked the Gibson

Comment: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1352) still works for iPhones regardless of silent switch position as of Jan 2016

Comment: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1352) works with target 9.3 in iOS 11 beta 2 even with vibration disabled + night mode.

Answer (score 26):

> **Important Note: Alert of Future Deprecation.**
>
> As of **iOS 9.0**, the **API** functions description for:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(inSystemSoundID: SystemSoundID)
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(inSystemSoundID: SystemSoundID)
```

includes the following note:

```
This function will be deprecated in a future release.
Use AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion or  
AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion instead.
```

> The right way to go will be using any of these two:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, nil)
```

or

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) {
 //your callback code when the vibration is done (it may not vibrate in iPod, but this callback will be always called)
}
```

> remember to `import AVFoundation`

Comment: you are missing the import statement

Comment: import AudioToolbox.AudioServices

Comment: i did it myself, is just with the AVFoundation one.

Comment: Anyway to set duration of vibration?

Comment: You are going to need to concatenate several calls, use a time lapse in between every new call

Comment: The deprecation warning no longer exists.

Answer (score 12):

For an iPhone 7/7 Plus or newer, use these three Haptic feedback APIs.

## Available APIs

### For notifications:

```
let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
generator.notificationOccured(style: .error)
```

Available styles are `.error`, `.success`, and `.warning`. Each has its own distinctive feel.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinotificationfeedbackgenerator):

> A concrete `UIFeedbackGenerator` subclass that creates haptics to communicate successes, failures, and warnings.

### For simple vibrations:

```
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
generator.impactOccured()
```

Available styles are `.heavy`, `.medium`, and `.light`. These are simple vibrations with varying degrees of "hardness".

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator):

> A concrete `UIFeedbackGenerator` subclass that creates haptics to simulate physical impacts

#### For when the user selected an item

```
let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
generator.selectionChanged()
```

This is the least noticeable of all the haptics, and so is the most suitable for when haptics should not be taking over the app experience.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiselectionfeedbackgenerator):

> A concrete `UIFeedbackGenerator` subclass that creates haptics to indicate a change in selection.

## Notes

There are a couple of things worth remembering when using these APIs.

#### Note A

**You do not actually create the haptic.** You *request the system* generate a haptic. The system will decide based on the below:

- If haptics are possible on the device (whether it has a Taptic Engine in this case)
- Whether the app may record audio (haptics do not generate during recording to prevent unwanted interference)
- Whether haptics are enabled in system Settings.

Therefore, the system will silently ignore your request for a haptic if it is not possible. If this is due to an unsupported device, you could try this:

```
func haptic() {
    // Get whether the device can generate haptics or not
    // If feedbackSupportLevel is nil, will assign 0
    let feedbackSupportLevel = UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "_feedbackSupportLevel") as? Int ?? 0

    switch feedbackSupportLevel { 
    case 2:
        // 2 means the device has a Taptic Engine
        // Put Taptic Engine code here, using the APIs explained above

    case 1: 
    // 1 means no Taptic Engine, but will support AudioToolbox
    // AudioToolbox code from the myriad of other answers!

    default: // 0
        // No haptic support
        // Do something else, like a beeping noise or LED flash instead of haptics
    }
```

Substitute the comments in the `switch`-`case` statements, and this haptic generation code will be portable to other iOS devices. It will generate the highest level of haptic possible.

#### Note B

- Due to the fact that generating haptics is a *hardware*-level task, there may be latency between when you *call* the haptic-generation code, and when it *actually happens.* For this reason, the Taptic Engine APIs all have a `prepare()` method, to put it in a state of readiness. Using your Game Over example: You may know that the game is about to end, by the user having very low HP, or a dangerous monster being near them.
- If you don't generate a haptic within a few seconds, the Taptic Engine will go back into an idle state (to save battery life)

In this case, preparing the Taptic Engine would create a higher-quality, more responsive experience.

For example, let's say your app uses a pan gesture recogniser to change the portion of the world visible. You want a haptic to generate when the user 'looks' round 360 degrees. Here is how you could use `prepare()`:

```
@IBAction func userChangedViewablePortionOfWorld(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecogniser!) {

    haptic = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)

    switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            // The user started dragging the screen.
            haptic.prepare()

        case .changed:
            // The user trying to 'look' in another direction
            // Code to change viewable portion of the virtual world

            if virtualWorldViewpointDegreeMiddle = 360.0 { 
                haptic.impactOccured()
            }
        
        default:
            break

}
```

Comment: Just remember to `import UIKit`!

Comment: You don't want to create a new instance of `haptic` inside this method. You are not calling `impactOccured` on the same instance that you call `prepare`.

Comment: Hello @Benj I want to implement vibration with audio recording and haptic does not work while recording.

Comment: @DikenShah as stated, I believe I read somewhere this is a deliberate move to minimise microphone interference. As microphones detect vibrations, and the Taptic Engine **makes** vibrations, this would clearly be an issue.

Comment: @Div I found the solution. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5):

And if you're using Xamarin (monotouch) framework, simply call

```
SystemSound.Vibrate.PlayAlertSound()
```

Answer (score 5):

In my travels I have found that if you try either of the following while you are recording audio, the device will not vibrate even if it is enabled.

```
1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

My method was called at a specific time in the measurement of the devices movements. I had to stop the recording and then restart it after the vibration had occurred.

It looked like this.

```
-(void)vibrate {
    [recorder stop];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    [recorder start];
}
```

`recorder` is an AVRecorder instance.

Hope this helps others that have had the same problem before.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 10, and on newer iPhones, you can also use haptic API. This haptic feedback is softer than the AudioToolbox API.

For your GAME OVER scenario, a heavy UI impact feedback should be suitable.

`UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy).impactOccurred()`

You could use the [other haptic feedback styles](https://samwize.com/2018/04/30/how-to-vibrate-an-iphone/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the AVCaptureSession.
AudioToolbox was in project's build phases and it was imported but still didn't work. In order to make it work I stopped the session before vibration and continued on after that.

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
...
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;
...
- (void)vibratePhone;
{
  [self.session stopRunning];
     NSLog(@"vibratePhone %@",@"here");
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
    {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); 
    }
    else
    {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
  [self.session startRunning];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
import AVFoundation
...
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use

1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

for iPhone and few newer iPods.

2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

for iPads.

Comment: iPod touches and iPads can't vibrate.

Comment: on a device with no vibration capability (like iPod Touch) 
                       this will do nothing