# How to do shake the iPhone using Cocos 2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, shake

I can detect shake in iPhone using Cocos 2D when I use:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
```

Now, I want to do shake the iPhone using Cocos 2D. Who can help me?

Comment: You mean you want the phone to vibrate?

Comment: i found a solution for this happen, that is: AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Comment: @NguyenThap Put your iPhone into your washing machine and turn it on. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS Simulator, click "Hardware" and in the drop down menu you will see "Shake Gesture"... click that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot physically shake your iPhone using Cocos2d. But if you want to vibrate your phone programatically, check this:
[Making the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)