# Making the device vibrate

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to vibrate iOS device through code.

I have used the following methods. But I am not being able to do that.

- 1) `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`
- 2) `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

When I run my game on ipod or ipad.

Comment: Are you sure the device can vibrate at all?

Comment: Only the iPod Touch 4G and newer can vibrate.  iPads cannot vibrate.  They have no vibration motors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the iPhone vibrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

Answer (score 0):

iPads doesn't support physical vibration. You can use these codes only in case of iPhones and newer versions of iPod.