# NSOperationQueue Heisenbug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsoperationqueue

I'm working on an app that calls `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` from a loop in a separate thread launched with `performSelectorInBackground`. For some reason, the app only vibrates reliably when the entire app is running in the background. I tried calling the vibrate function from a block sent to the main NSOperationQueue, but it's still only consistent when in the background. Unless, of course, I throw a `NSLog()` call into the operation block:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"VIBRATING");
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}];
```

With the NSLog call, it runs as intended regardless of where it's running.

Any idea why this is? All suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: maybe it is a threading issue? NSLog will force a certain synrchonization

Comment: oh and no that AudioServicesPlayAlertSound is async anyways

Answer (score 1):

The header file documentation for `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` states

> Play the provided SystemSoundID with AlertSound behavior.

I would imagine that it simply does not play while the app is considered active and front-most. Maybe try using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` instead?

Comment: Very good theory, but changing the function didn't fix it. Thanks though

Comment: I suspect that NSLog is changing things just enough to cause it to work in that case. Instead of NSLog, try using Xcode's ability to set a breakpoint and print output. This way, you avoid the NSLog - which changes your code - but you can still break (and spit out text and auto-continue.) Simply right-click on breakpoint in Xcode to alter these settings. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to [Making the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate) solved my problem. For some reason, the iPhone doesn't like to vibrate while recording audio. So the obvious solution is to stop recording before vibrating:

```
[_recorder stop];
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
[_recorder record];
```

Still, I'm not sure why the NSLog has any effect, and I still don't see why it worked just fine without the above fix while running in the background.

Comment: That is stated in the documentation of AudioServicesPlayAlertSound, it says: .... However, the device does not vibrate if your app’s audio session is configured with the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord audio session category. This ensures that vibration doesn’t interfere with audio recording.....