# Vibrate for a long time?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, vibration

I want to make an app where while the user is pushing down a button the phone vibrates until the user releases the button.

Ive searched around and I haven't found a way to make it a long vibrate, except for a very old tutorial from 2009 which seems to be outdated.

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial you found, it still might work.

Comment: Yea but people in the comments of it say its bugging or something, and that Apple is not accepting that method. Link to the tutorial: http://www.kimballlarsen.com/2009/12/22/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-for-a-long-time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not allowed by Apple to use the vibration as you want to:

> **Vibration.**   It is not permitted to use continuous vibration in your
>   apps – **short bursts as warnings is all that is allowed**.   Don’t bother
>   trying to set up a timer to keep the vibration going, it will cause
>   your app to be rejected.

It's not the method, but the result, that's not permitted.

Source: http://10base-t.com/unofficial-appstore-rejection-criteria/

Comment: Yea thats what i feared. Thanks

Comment: This was 2 years ago. Have review guidelines changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

repeat this line in between you start-stop vibrate. 
don't forgot to add and import

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

framework to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Look on these options,

```
1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

also
[Making the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

And, you need to import AudioToolBox framework,

```
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```