# Programmatically trigger shake event iOS

Tags: ios, triggers, delegates, shake

How can I programmatically trigger the shake event in iOS?

I've tried the following but it keeps crashing...

```
+ (void)shake {
    NSLog(@"TEST");

    UIMotionEventProxy *m = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIMotionEvent") alloc] _init];

    m->_subtype = UIEventSubtypeMotionShake;
    m->_shakeState = 1;

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] motionBegan:UIEventSubtypeMotionShake withEvent:m];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] motionEnded:UIEventSubtypeMotionShake withEvent:m];
}
```

What does apple do in the simulator under `Hardware > Shake Gesture`?

Comment: I dont really understand why this is needed. If you just need to have a vibration you could try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate

Comment: Take a look through this tutorial
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/detect-shake-gesture-on-a-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the UIMotionEventProxy class (adding two setter methods) seemed to do the trick. I simply added two methods `setShakeState` and `_setSubtype`, shown below.

```
-(void)setShakeState:(int)fp8 {
    _shakeState = fp8;
}
-(void)_setSubtype:(int)fp8 {
    _subtype = fp8;
}
```

I then changed my code to the following...

```
UIMotionEventProxy *m = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIMotionEvent") alloc] _init];

[m setShakeState:1];
[m _setSubtype:UIEventSubtypeMotionShake];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:m];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] motionBegan:UIEventSubtypeMotionShake withEvent:m];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] motionEnded:UIEventSubtypeMotionShake withEvent:m];
```

Seems to be working flawlessly for both simulator and physical device. [Here](https://www.mediafire.com/?cfxxwru2xoobb85) are main and header files available for download if anyone wants to see the full UIMotionEventProxy files.

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace

`UIMotionEventProxy *m = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIMotionEvent") alloc] _init];`

with

`UIMotionEventProxy *m = [[UIMotionEventProxy alloc] _init];`

I guess it's crushing when `NSClassFromString(@"UIMotionEvent")` returns nil.

Comment: See my answer, this was also part of the issue.

Comment: I do not understand. If m was created as it was supposed then m->_subtype = ... should work as well. If m was not created then adding setters should not help.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with memory usage, do not quite understand iOS yet to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use in Jailbreak app or Apple compliant use ?

For your question about simulator, Apple use a private function.

Here is a little explanation:

When you use "Shake Gesture", the simulator call sendButtonEvent:0x3fc

sendButtonEvent is a function in Simulator, who:

- get frontmostAppPort
- send a message via sendPurpleEvent or HIDEvent

In a jailbreak application, you can do something like (not tested, but should works):

```
struct UIEvent {
    int subtype;
    double timestamp;
    int type;
} * event;

bzero(event, sizeof(event));

event->type = UIEventTypeMotion;
event->subtype = UIEventSubtypeMotionShake;
event->timestamp = GSCurrentEventTimestamp();

NSString* bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
mach_port_t port = GSCopyPurpleNamedPort([bundle UTF8String]);

GSEventRecord* record = (GSEventRecord*)event;
GSSendEvent(record, port);
```