# How can I use the code to shake the device in the test

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I have an app on iOS and I need to shake the simulator as part of UITests, how can this be implemented?

cmd+control+z do not offer, you need a solution within the code

Xcode 12.1, MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 I tried to use this type of code, but it didn't work out and I didn't find any other options either

```
func testChangingStand() {

            var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
                get {
                    return true
                }
            }

            func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
                if motion == .motionShake {
                    sleep(5)
                    let tablesQuery = app.tables
                    let checkStand = tablesQuery.staticTexts[""]
                    if waitFor(checkStand, to: .appear) {
                        tablesQuery.staticTexts[""].tap()
                    } else {
                        tablesQuery/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts[""]/*[[".cells.staticTexts[\"\"]",".staticTexts[\"\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()
                    }
                    tablesQuery.staticTexts["production"].tap()
                    tablesQuery.staticTexts["Legacy"].tap()
                    app.scrollViews.otherElements.staticTexts["API MODE"].tap()
                    app.switches.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
                }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Need to see the code that you are using to detect the shake.  Which version of Xcode, macOS are you using?

Comment: @MwcsMac Xcode 12.1, MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 
I tried to use this type of code, but it didn't work out and I didn't find any other options either
`func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?)`

Comment: Show the full code for the function as it is typed in your app.  A couple of key parts could be missing.

Comment: @MwcsMac add code in question

Comment: See this [SOanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55533672/4080925)

Comment: You do not _perform_ the shake, you _mock_ the shake. That is what testing is.