# iOS SDK :: vibration & plays a beep sound.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod

I need to vibrate iOS device, devices that don’t support vibration, Will plays a beep sound.

For this I am using

```
Import AudioToolbox.framework
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

It vibrate on iPhone device, but No sound on **iPad and iPod**. While refrences say that it will play sound. What I am doing wrong ?

[Making the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) seems to indicate that the iPod Touch, at least, should do nothing:  "Constants
kSystemSoundID_Vibrate
On the iPhone, use this constant with the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound function to invoke a brief vibration. On the iPod touch, does nothing."

Comment: Thanks @borrrden, You are looking into AudioServicesPlaySystemSound while I am using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound, Documentation say "Depending on the particular iOS device, this function plays a short sound and may invoke vibration. Calling this function does the following on various iOS devices:"

Comment: I realized that, and updated my comment with a different section from the documentation

Comment: Thanks, but it say  1)AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2)AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Both the functions vibrate the iPhone. But when you use the first function on devices that don’t support vibration, it plays a beep sound. The second function on the other hand does nothing on unsupported devices.  and I need to vibrate device and if no Hardware support then play beep sound.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but ... Have you checked that the devices are not muted? Stumbled upon that myself and wondered why the device didn't vibrate until I noticed that the mute switch was on :)

Comment: @Mangesh I trust the documentation more than a three year old stack overflow answer.

Comment: i tried this objective c code but the iphone doesnt vibrate, using latest xcode version, latest iphone Os and iphone 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the AudioSession:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;         
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  error:&err];
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);         
//or: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Comment: this code is use for Vibrate on / off for the perticular application ?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question @iPhoneDev.

Comment: i want to set on/off vibrate on switch. So, Which code i set on Switch = on/off ?