# Implicit declaration of function 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration' is invalid in c99

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio, vibration

I need 500ms seconds vibration for that i am using below code

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array ];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];    //stop for 500ms
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:500]];

[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"Intensity"];


 AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict);
```

AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration working perfectly but give warning as well as i am not able to release my application to app store.

I amd include AudioTools framework in my project

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a private API method, you are not allowed to use it. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate instead

Comment: Thanks **luk2302**                                   `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);` `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`          this 2 function vibrate phone but i need 500ms vibration and this method give me more than 500ms. I need just pinch of vibration.

Comment: It's impossible to hide private c API, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the function using `FOUNDATION_EXTERN` macro:

```
FOUNDATION_EXTERN AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(unsigned long, objc_object*, NSDictionary*)
```

But be ready to get rejected for private API usage, especially on US App Store.