# Set vibration sound to vibrate on iOS

Tags: ios, vibration

I'm creating an app where you can "send" vibrations to your contacts.
In IOS how do you set the sound for notifications from my app to vibrate, I want it to vibrate even when silent is *off*. Also I want the users to send *custom* vibration patterns, would that work or can you only play a sound once. It should work even when the app is *not in background*.

Comment: AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Comment: Does this work even when app is not in background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22843899/1254172 and yes, this will work both in background and foreground

Comment: What about when app is NOT in background!

Comment: If you have something like a local notification/push notification then the phone will vibrate when the phone is in the background (if the phone is on silent). The code we have posted here is for when the app is running and in the foreground. So yes it vibrates when the app is not in the background. By not in the background you mean currently active and being used yes?

Comment: No i mean is there a way to make sure that even if the app is not currently running in foreground or background, and it triggers a notification, that the notification sound will always be a vibration even if not on silent.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

```
1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Comment: It's work for you ? please accept my answer @user2885424