# issue while vibrating iPhone ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, vibration

I want to `vibrate` and `flash light` simultaneously.But when I Use following code i only get `flash light`.

```
if (some condition)
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    [self setTorch:YES];
}
```

But when i use only

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

my phone vibrates.

I am unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[May be it will useful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725039/3589771)

find this [Gonna Vibrate the device to alert the user? Read this first](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/)

Both the functions vibrate the iPhone. But when you use the first function on devices that don’t support vibration, it plays a beep sound. The second function on the other hand does nothing on unsupported devices. So if you are going to vibrate the device continuously, as a alert, common sense says, use function 2.

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```