# Notification sound iOS always vibrate for an app?

Tags: ios, notifications, vibration

If my app is open or not open, and not running in background or foreground ( basically I **always** ) want the notification sound for my app to be a vibration or set of vibrations. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @matt any notification, like if someone sends me a message through this app, and I get a notification, I want the sound to be a buzz

Comment: Like in iMessage, if I receive a SMS I get a notification, now let's say my screen is locked, I will get one on the lockscreen, if my device is unlocked it'll pop up at the top, but if I haven't opened iMessage that day or I quit the app by swiping up on multitasking view then I can still get a notification

Comment: So I want it to always give me a notification that's a vibration

Comment: If that's what it's called then yeah,

Comment: Yeap, a Ui local notif

Comment: Take reference from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate