# Is there a way to programatically toggle vibrate?

Tags: objective-c

In objective-c for iOS dev, is there any way to programatically toggle the vibrate on/off? And also to check its current state?

If there is, where might I find it in documentation? I've looked and cannot find it so maybe it's not possible?

Edit: I don't mean to make the phone vibrate. What I mean is that when the phone is on silent there is a toggle to have vibration on/off. Can this be controlled programatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the iPhone vibrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

Comment: I think it's not possible to toggle the vibration state as it's up to a physical button. What you can do is to make the phone vibrate programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question with a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't.**
This is a system defined property (that your user can access from `Settings`).
None of the iOS APIs allow such kind of control.

Comment: Thanks @QuentinHayot - just the clarification I needed.

Comment: You are welcome :) In general any "system's behavior changing" features won't have a public API in iOS.