# Vibrate iPhone 6S manually like peek and pop?

Tags: ios, vibration, iphone-vibrate, peek-pop

How can I manually trigger a single click-like vibration like the ones that happen when using peek&pop, or application shortcuts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate

Comment: @Lefteris that question is about vibration in general, I am talking about the short vibration (it feels like a click) when peek and pop activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that these guys have found a way to do it for iOS 9 for phones with Taptic Engine (including the iPhone 6S). http://unifiedsense.com/development/using-taptic-engine-on-ios.html I'm not sure if it applies to iOS 8 or any other phones. They've essentially retrieved the Taptic Engine interface from `UIDevice` and called `actuateFeedback` with an integer corresponding to Peek or Pop.

Unfortunately these apps would likely be rejected by the App Store, if that's your intention.

Answer (score 24):

This method is easy to implement and it works really well (I tried it myself)

```
import AudioToolbox

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // Peek feedback
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520) // Pop feedback
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521) // Three pulses feedback
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 7.1.2, but similar something vaguely similar can be achieved with vibration codes 1011 and 1311 as per [this wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices).