# iOS System Sound not being played

Tags: ios, xcode, system-sounds

I am trying to implement playing of system sound in my app running on iOS 10.3.1
The problem i am experiencing is that when i am in viewDidLoad, when the app is being debugged, the sound is being played. When the app is running normally, it is always vibrating.

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(1107, nil);
```

When i want to use this same system sound, in a specific location in the app, the appropriate location which should produce sound, it doesn't do anything, no sound nor vibrate in debugging mode or normal run.

I don't see any errors nor warning when the app is running. 
EDIT* Added some code where i use it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(1107, nil);
    //AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(1100, nil); (same)
}
```

This always does only vibrate, doesn't matter if turned on the ringer, or whether it is connected the phone to Xcode or not.

I have this imported, if it means anything:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "CoreLocationController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you using device or simulator?

Comment: device, 6s, connected to Xcode for debugging.

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: does it have to be the playing of the sound to the main queue? that is the only thing i can think of. The places where i want to use the system sound, that it is not on the main queue, but in viewDidLoad, i don't see a reason why doesn't work.

Comment: This might seem too obvious, but have you checked whether or not your volume is turned up?

Comment: Yes, i have it switched to the on position, and i checked when i lock the phone, can hear sound.

Comment: Is there any settings in the settings, that i have to specify for system sound? Maybe i missed something there.

Comment: AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1107) i tried that in viewdidload and it worked.

Comment: yes, i have it in another application, and it works too, but in this current one, i can't seem to find the issue why it is not working.

Comment: xcode 8.3.2, and deployment target 9.0

Comment: Ok, so some improvement, now in viewDidLoad, it plays. But then in a specific function, it doesnt

Comment: any suggestions? Can it do anything with AVAudioSession? since i am using that

Comment: Check in that specific method which thread you are on?

Answer (score 3):

You can find some interesting stuff in the headers of the Framework AVFAudio.

[Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIfiu.png)

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wk42.png)

You should check this post, I think it might help you.

[How to play Alert Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate/29345183)

```
1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

> Both of the functions vibrate the iPhone. But, when you use the first function on devices that don’t support vibration, it plays a beep sound. The second function, on the other hand, does nothing on unsupported devices. So if you are going to vibrate the device continuously, as an alert, common sense says, use function 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are two volume buttons (volume up and volume down). Beside the volume up button, there is a toggle(switch) button, which is actually a mute button.