# make iPhone vibrate programmatically through IF Else statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

I have two buttons. One button adds up, one button adds down. The question is when I certain number such as lets say 22 is in the text area, the phone vibrates for a certain mount of time. Here is my code for it:

What I am trying to say is IF Label Displays "22" THEN VIBRATE PHONE... The question is how do i go about writing this.. I'm still learning so any help regarding this would be much appreciated! Here is my code so far:

```
#import "StartCountViewController.h"
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h"

@implementation StartCountViewController


int Count=0;

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    startCount.text = @"0";

}


- (IBAction)addNumber {

    if(Count >= 999) return;

    NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", Count++];
    startCount.text = numValue;
    [numValue release];

}

- (IBAction)vibrate {


}
- (IBAction)subtractNumber {

    if(Count <= -35) return;

    NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", Count--];
    startCount.text = numValue;
    [numValue release]; 
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Making the iPhone vibrate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate

Comment: Your `vibrate` method is empty.

Comment: The reason why it is empty because im not sure on how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [Programmatically make the iPhone vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080442/programmatically-make-the-iphone-vibrate)

Having said that, I think your code is still going to have errors, and the syntax seems deprecated.

Here's an example.  I didn't try this on an actual iphone which would be required to test the vibration, but it should work provided you add the *AudioToolbox framework* to your project, and of course your XIB file has the necessary connections:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberLabel;
- (IBAction)addNumber:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)subtractNumber:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  int count;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize numberLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  count = 0;
  [self updateCount];
  [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  [self setNumberLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
  [numberLabel release];
  [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)addNumber:(id)sender 
{
  if(count >= 999) {
    return [self vibrate];
  }; // ignore numbers larger than 999
  count++;
  [self updateCount];
}

- (IBAction)subtractNumber:(id)sender 
{
  if(count <= -35) {
    return [self vibrate];
  }; // ignore numbers less than -35
  count--;
  [self updateCount];
}

-(void)updateCount 
{
  NSString *countStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",count];
  [self.numberLabel setText:countStr];
  [countStr release];
}

-(void)vibrate 
{
  NSLog(@"I'm vibrating");
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
@end
```